# Preferred way to write elements of the direct sum of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory, products, limits-colimits

Suppose $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over the same field and $V\oplus W$ is
their direct sum. Reading through the literature I found essentially two
ways of writing elements of $V\oplus W$.

1.) We have the 'product like description' $(v,w)\in V\oplus W$

2.) We have $v+w\in V\oplus W$

Is there a correct or preferred way to write the elements?

I mean the direct sum is the **co**product in the category of vector spaces
not the product, so the first one is eventually misleading 
(although the product $V\times W$ is the same here, this is only for finite many factors/terms)

On the other side, the second one can eventually be misleading. For
example, consider $a+b+c+d \in V\oplus W$. What does $+$ mean here? Is it the
$+$ from $V$ or from $W$ or from the direct sum? Is $b \in V$ or $b\in W$ ? You can't say ....

Comment: You can also write $v\oplus w$. $a+b+c+d$ is okay, because we are really just just writing $w$ when we mean $(0,w)$ and $v$ when we mean $(v,0)$. So long as we know which of $a,b,c,d$ is in $V,W,$ or $V\oplus W$, it isn't confusing. But if $W=V$, or even $W\subseteq V$, or visa versa, then it is ambiguous, of course.

Comment: I like the $v\oplus w$. Thought about it myself, but couldn't find it in the literature. Have you any 'example-book' or something, that uses this? -- For the $a+b+c+d$ the problem is, I think, that we don't know where the single terms are from, because you can't see. So this one depends on cleverness and that certainly not a good idea in general.

Comment: I've seen $v\otimes w$ for elements of $V\otimes W$. I'm sure I've seen $v\oplus w$ in some place or other, but it isn't common.

Comment: But its certainly the most fail-save version.

Comment: I agree with Jim, though, I don't really see anything ambiguous with the ordered pair.

Comment: THen tell me, is $b\in V$ or $b\in W$ in the previous example? One way to put is like $(a +_V b) \oplus (c +_W d)$ another is $a \oplus (b+_W c +_W d)$ In a strict type-logic environmwnt you would get the "type-missmatch error", since the ymbol $+$ could either mean $+_V$ or $\oplus$ or $+_W$.

Comment: I was agreeing with Jim's answer, using $(v,w)$, not that expression. As I said, you couldn't write $a+b+c+d$ if you didn't know implicitly which vector space each element was in. That goes without saying. But if you have that information, there is no ambiguity in writing $a+b+c+d$.

Comment: Sorry. Jims answer?

Comment: Do you see that marker below, that says "1 Answer." Then several paragraphs and then text "Answered (some time) Jim." That's Jim's answer. Perhaps you need to reload the page?

Comment: Oh of course! Stupid. Had to reload...

Comment: A typical example is polynomials. We often write $1+xy+2+x^2$, but polynomials are really a graded ring - a direct sum of $1$-dimensional vector spaces with a multiplication added. The terms make clear which vector space we are taking each term from.

Comment: Right. Here it is not ambiguous at all.

Comment: The key is to use the notation that makes things clear. Consistent notation is irritating. When talking about $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$, we'll often mention $2$, when we mean $2+m\mathbb Z$. Being a stickler for notation doesn't really get you much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is not misleading, the notation $(v, w)$ does not imply product vs. coproduct, it's just notation for a tuple.  If we had infinitely many summands (so that product $\neq$ coproduct) then writing $(v_i)$ just indicates that you have a tuple indexed by $i$.  It does not tell you whether that tuple has finite support or not and when it does have finite support this doesn't imply that you're considering the coproduct, elements of the product can have finite support as well (it's just not a requirement for the product).

The notation $(v, w)$ just indicates tuples.  As with most notations you have to either say explicitly or make sure it's clear from context in what domain you consider that element to be living.

The notation $v + w$ is also just as good though you're correct that you have to be extra careful to say where things live because the notation no longer indicates that $v$ is from the left factor and $w$ is from the right.

So use whichever you like, there is no correct choice or preference.  The thing to remember about *all* notation is that no matter how clear you think it is, it's never perfect.  You will always need to include prose to explain your mathematics.

Comment: Yes ok. The question of course remains, why the $v\oplus w \in V\oplus W$ is not used that often.

Comment: It's not used because $(v, w)$ already suffices for that purpose.